# Azurite hangs and errs eventually when I tried to delete a blog storage file or upload a file

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azurite, azure-storage-explorer

Azurite hangs and errs eventually when I tried to delete a blob storage file using Azure Storage Explorer. I uses Putty to connect remote Azure container running linux docker. I mapped 127.0.0.0:5051 to remote 10000 port. The command line is "E:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer\StorageExplorer.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors. I can connect to the server and can create folders and can delete table entries.

Finally I got this error message after a long hang: {
"message": ""failed to perform remove command due to error: cannot start job due to error: cannot list files due to reason -> github.com/Azure/azure-pipeline-go/pipeline.NewError, C:/Users/VssAdministrator/go/pkg/mod/github.com/!azure/azure-pipeline-go@v0.2.4-0.20220425205405-09e6f201e1e4/pipeline/error.go:157\nHTTP request failed\n\nGet \"https://127.0.0.1:5051/account1/grainstate?comp=list&delimiter=%2F&include=metadata&prefix=chunk-chunk%2F105-ACTIVE-ACTIVE%212432.1--1003552052.json%2F&restype=container&se=2023-09-24T18%3A56%3A15Z&sig=-REDACTED-&sp=rdl&sr=c&sv=2018-03-28&timeout=901\": x509: cannot validate certificate for 127.0.0.1 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs\n.\n""
}

I tried to search the error and nothing significant. Table and queue is OK.